# when alert box is poped up,background goes blank

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Calling from this page:

**contact.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ctrlWebMessage=WebApplication1.About;
    ctrlWebMessage.Show(this.Page, "Please enter my name");
}
```

**about.aspx.cs -**

```
public void Show(System.Web.UI.Page page, string strMessage) {
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "PopUp",
        "<script>showDialogModal('MMF Portal', '" + strTmp + "')</script>");
}
```

**about.aspx**

```
function showDialogModal(message) {
    var confirm = window.alert(message)
    if (confirm) {
        return "Yes";
        `enter code here`
    } else {
        `enter code here`
        return "No";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the background does not go blank, it NEVER displays (and that is a significant different issue). When you click ok on that dialog box, then the rest of the page does display, right?

So, I would consider adopting some kind of toast message, or some kind of non blocking message box.

So, if that alert() is the first thing to display then it does display, and thus the result of the page is halted from display.

So, you need to use a dailog that is non blocking (jquery.UI) is really nice.

Remember full page post back, run your code behind and then inject a alert dialog.
Now, code behind is done, and WHOLE page goes back to client, it loads into the browser, and first thing that runs is the alert script (so, page looks blank - it just not had a chance to re-plot).

You can as a quick workaround put in a delay before the alert() is to pop up.

Say, like this:

```
 string myscript 
    = "setTimeout(function() { alert('Hello to world')}, 500)";

 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "MyPop", myscript, true);
```

So above will work, but I suggest you consider a jquery.UI dialog - it will work since they are async in nature.